# Filling List with XML content in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, list, parsing

I'm trying to retrieve information from a XML file located in raw resources which structure is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<languages>
  <language code="ab">Abkhazian</language>
  <language code="aa">Afar</language>
  <language code="af">Afrikaans</language>
  <language code="sq">Albanian</language>
 ...
```

What I've got to do is fill a List with the values of the languages, like 'Abkhazian','Afar',... I tried using XMLPullParser, but I don't know how to retrieve the name of the language, since it's not a field.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what about you will use normal `string-array`?

```
<string-array name="languages">
   <item>Abkhazian</item>
   <item>Afar</item>
   <item>Afrikaans</item>
</string-array>
```

then call `String[] langs = getResources().getStringArray(R.id.languages);`

Or try to use classic **W3C DOM Parser**:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Document doc;
doc = f.newDocumentBuilder().parse(<xml>);
NodeList langs = doc.getElementsByTagName("languages");
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
String lang = null;
for (int i = 0; i < langs.getLength(); i++) {
Node n = langs.item(i);
if (n.getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
   lang = n.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
   data.add(lang);
}
```

Comment: Worked! I had to change "languages" for "language" in your code, but all worked as excepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

presuming that you have declared your parser as:

```
XmlPullParser parser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
parser.setInput(is, null);   //'is' is the InputStream corresponding to your xml file
```

once you reach a tag, you can retrieve the data stored within it using:

```
String language = parser.nextText();
```

Go through this tutorial for more details:
http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/android-xml-adventure-parsing-xml-data-with-xmlpullparser/